# Windows Phone 8.1 Push Messaging (WNS) with Azure Notification Hub doesn't work properly

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I'm playing around with Universal Apps for WinRT and WP 8.1 (not the Silverlight stuff).

As for the regular Windows 8.1 store app, the push notification from the azure notification hub works quite well and really fast (within a few seconds), I have problems when I push to my WindowsPhone 8.1 device. After connecting to the WNS-service (see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/#connecting-app) it works for about 15 minutes. After that, the messages don't arrive any more?

When I take a look to the Azure-Push-Debugger I can see that the message was sent to the push service correctly. The strange thing is, that push messages sent with the old fashioned way (MPNS+Silverlight) works pretty good either.

Is there anybody who can confirm this strange behaviour with WP 8.1 apps? Any ideas to solve the problem?

Thanks with regards, Phil

Answer (score 1):

Now I know the anwser...

As described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941100(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UTDS it seems that probably my carrier (Austria - tele.ring) is the problem. If I activate Wifi, it works all the time. If I disconnect Wifi and make use of the carrier's internet connection, it simply doesn't work as expected (see question above).

Best regards, Phil

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question. I was not aware that some carriers could cause this. Good to know! +1